# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component warning when using setInterval and clearing the interval. Why?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, setinterval, use-effect

I'm testing a component that uses a hook to update a value every 30 secs. It does this by calling `setInterval` every thirty seconds. I'm clearing this interval in the hook's `useEffect` hook. When I run the tests in Jest, I get the `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component`. I'm clearing the interval in the cleanup function of the useEffect hook, but that still doesn't fix the issue.

If I set a `isCanceled` boolean to `true` in the cleanup function, and check for the truthiness of that value before calling the setter, I no longer get the issue. My question is: I don't quite understand why that works. I understand there must be a gap after the component unmounts and before `clearInterval` gets invoked where the contents of `setInterval` run, but I don't see it. Can anyone explain? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
const useCalculatedMinutes = (time: EpochTime): string => {
    let isCanceled = false;
    const [mins, setMins] = useState(getMinutesFromNow(time));
    const THIRTY_SECONDS = 30000;

    const updateMinutesRegularly = () => {
        return setInterval(() => {
            // if (!isCanceled) { // This check will prevent the warning from happening.
                setMins(getMinutesFromNow(time));
            // }
        }, THIRTY_SECONDS);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = updateMinutesRegularly();
        return () => {
            // isCanceled = true; // Doing this to indicate the component is now unmounted; this works.
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, [mins]);

    return mins;
};
```

EDIT: I'm also using Jest's `runOnlyPendingTimers` function. Test is below:

```
it('increments the time after one minute', async () => {
    const ONE_MINUTE_FROM_NOW = Date.now() + 60100 * 1;
    renderDashboardScreen();
    await waitForElementToBeRemoved(screen.getByText(/Loading.../));
    expect(screen.getByText(/10 mins/)).toBeInTheDocument();
    await waitFor(() => {
      jest
       .spyOn(global.Date, 'now')
       .mockImplementation(() => ONE_MINUTE_FROM_NOW);
        jest.runOnlyPendingTimers(60000);
      });
        expect(await screen.findByText(/11 mins/)).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

Additionally, I have other tests in the file. If I comment out all of the others, I don't get the warning. If I uncomment any of the other tests, I get the warning again.
```

Comment: Changes to local variables such as `isCanceled` here (if you could change it, and you can't since it's const) wouldn't persist between rerenders and you'd likely bump into a stale closure issue reading it. You'd need a ref to box the variable.

Comment: Sorry, my linter converted it from `let` to `const` after I commented its usage out.

Comment: Okay, so a ref would work here. Why do I need a ref; why doesn't the clearInterval call suffice?

Comment: Even when I reference the setInterval function in a useRef I still get the issue.

Comment: I was not getting the warning when running the test on its own, but was receiving it when running multiple tests. Running jest.clearAllTimers() resolved the issue.

Comment: If you need to manually clean timers in tests, they're probably also leaking in production..?

Comment: Quite possibly (we're not in prod yet, but I get your point) and manually clearing them may not be solving the issue. I get this warning with only one interval, and not all of them.  I'm not sure what is happening, since I'm calling `clearInterval` in the cleanup hook. Dan Abramov's useInterval hook wasn't solving the issue for me either.

Comment: The `react-use` library has been pretty useful – https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useInterval.md might do the trick for you.

Comment: It's a neat hook, though the issue was still happening when I was using Dan Abramov's `useInterval` hook. 

Found the issue; i need to manually call `cleanup()` from React Testing Library. The App wasn't being properly torn down and was persisting state for each test.